# PHP/MYSQL and latin letters

Tags: php, mysql

So i've built a php application that is in Serbian so it uses latin letters like Ššđććžćđšž etc. Writing it in the database is no problem, everything works fine, but here is the problem:

When i try to search some data from database in my application php confuses š with s, so for example if i search for "skola" it will pull both "skola" and "škola" from database which is a big problem. Do you have any idea why is that happening?
Btw database is set to utf8

Comment: there are different utf8 collations that cause the searching and ordering to work different. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html for starters.

Comment: show us your search code